# QUERY TO FIND THE RECORDS WHICH ARE HAVING with COLUMN3 null or with empty VALUE IN COLUMN4

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

Suppose i have a table with name `customers` and columns in it  or like: `id, site id, designid, material id....` now i want the output to find out the record of the table which are having `siteid is null` or with `empty` design id values

i have tried these both

```
select T.ID,T.siteID, T.DESIGNID from #temp2 as T 
join #temp2 as T1 on T.SiteID=T1.SiteID where T.DESIGNID=null or T.SiteID=Null
```

or

```
select T.ID,T.siteID, T.DESIGNID from #temp2 as T 
WHERE T.DESIGNID=null or T.SiteID=Null
```

Comment: dID U TYR WITH 
select T.ID,T.siteID, T.DESIGNID from #temp2 as T WHERE T.DESIGNID IS null or T.SiteID IS Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Select count(*) 
From CUSTOMERS  
Where SITE_ID = 0 or SITEID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your question exactly, But check below query as of my understanding.

```
select T.ID,T.siteID, T.DESIGNID from #temp2 as T WHERE T.DESIGNID IS null or LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.DESIGNID)))=0 or T.SiteID IS Null
```